# ГОСТ Р 34.11-94

Tags: криптография, java, хеширование

Пытался на днях сделать (велосипед) реализацию [ГОСТ'овского](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_%D0%A0_34.11-94) шифрования.
Всё делаю по тому, как описано в ссылке выше. Но.
На выходе должен получить результат от хэширования КриптоПро'шной таблицей замен

```
GOST("abc") = b285056dbf18d7392d7677369524dd14747459ed8143997e163b2986f92fd42c
```

А получаю

```
GOST("abc") = ��m��9-vw6�$�ttY�C�~;)��
```

И в лучшем случае, разобравшись с кодировками

```
GOST("abc") = І…mїЧ9-vw6•$ЭttYнЃC™~;)†щ/Ф,
```

Вопрос: если нормальные, тонкие (1 внешний + внутренние, костыли если что - допишу), рачитывающие хэш *правильно* реализации сего на Java или близком к нему?

---

**UPD:**
Вообщем, на выходе получается такой массив byte:

```
[-78, -123, 5, 109, -65, 24, -41, 57, 45, 118, 119, 54, -107, 36, -35, 20, 116, 116, 89, -19, -127, 67, -103, 126, 22, 59, 41, -122, -7, -44, 44]
```

Я так понял переводим в шестнадцатиричную кажое и конкатенируем и будет мне счастье?

---

**UPD2:**
Прислушался к [[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) - результат

```
B2 85 05 6D BF 18 D7 39 2D 76 77 36 95 24 DD 14 74 74 59 ED 81 43 99 7E 16 3B 29 86 F9 2F D4 2C
```

Что вполне устраивает. Спасибо всем за внимание :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причем тут кодировки? Надо набор байтов отображать не "as-is", а в виде 16-тиричных символов.

Comment: @Barmaley, спасибо, гуру. Вы меня выручаете как всегда:)

Comment: @stck обращайтесь :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну вот в самом низу

```
GOST ("abc") = F3134348C44FB1B2A277729E2285EBB5CB5E0F29C975BC753B70497C06A4D51D
```

А у тебя

```
GOST("abc") = b285056dbf18d7392d7677369524dd14747459ed8143997e163b2986f92fd42c
```

и это явно вообще другое нежели что ты написал.
+ ко всему ты наверное используешь UTF-8 по-этому у тебя есть такое

```
GOST("abc") = ��m��9-vw6�$�ttY�C�~;)��
```

т.е. ровно половинка от нужного символа. Госты разрабатывались раньше под 1-2 кодировки и не знали что их использование будет работать на таблице где каждый символ занимает 2 байта (если я сейчас правильно написал, и вообще проснулся в четверг) :)

А следовательно они просто не рассчитаны на какие-то кодировки, и их нужно изменять, даже не их изменять, а использование стандартных функций для работы с кодировками.

Comment: Хм, разве стандарты шифрования заточены под текст? Им же (на сколько я знаю) всё равно что шифровать. А то что на выходе просто определённое количество бит и всё. Главное, если это блочный шифр, чтобы блоки были нужного рамера и всё.

Comment: @Shrek, там различаются таблицы заменты - ту которую ты написал "в самом низу" - ГОСТ хеш с «тестовым» набором параметров. Которую написал я, взята оттуда же, только использовалась таблица замены КриптоПро. Этот результат я получил переводом byte массива в строку. Но про кодировки - однозначно плюс тебе. Буду в ту сторону копать

Comment: Современная криптография не использует символы в какой-либо кодировке, а всегда работает с числами. Гостовой хэш-функции все равно, как кто-то ранее интерпретировал поданный ей на вход поток битов

Comment: Ну логично что ей будет по боку что криптовать, но тут все-таки вопрос в кодировке.

Answer (score 1):

Если что - вот несколько корявый, но полностью рабочий и протестированный код, реализующий `ГОСТ Р 34.11-94`: http://zinal.livejournal.com/11662.html ([репозиторий](https://github.com/zinal/gosthash))

Если руки дойдут, сделаю вариант со свежим `ГОСТ` и оформлю как провайдер `Java Crypto`.