# Как генерируются ключи для хеширования в стандарте ГОСТ Р 34.11-94?

Tags: c#, шифрование, хеширование

Просмотрев ответ на вопрос
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154671/ГОСТ-Р-34-11-94](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/154671/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2-%D0%A0-34-11-94), я не смогла найти решение проблемы.
Не могу понять как хранить сообщение M и как генерируются ключи. Почему ключ состоит из 64 символов, а в документации говорится о 32?
В примере указано сообщение, которое необходимо хешировать

```
M   =   73657479    62203233    3D687467    6Е656С20
        2С656761    7373656D    20736920    73696854
```

И ключи, которые должны получиться

```
K1  =   733D2C20    65686573    74746769    79676120
        626Е7373    20657369    326С6568    33206D54
K2  =   110C733D    0D166568    130E7474    06417967
        1D00626E    161A2065    090D326C    4D393320
K3  =   80B111F3    730DF216    850013F1    C7E1F941
        620C1DFF    3ABAE91A    3FA109F2    F513B239
K4  =   A0E2804E    FF1B73F2    ECE27A00    E7B8C7E1
        EE1D620C    AC0CC5BA    A804C05E    A18B0AEC
```

Если следовать данному алгоритму:

[image: алгоритм]

1. Присвоить значения

`i: = 1, U: = H, V: =M.`

2. Выполнить вычисление

`W = U⨁ ̅V, K1 = P(W)`

3. Присвоить i:

`=i+1`.

4. Проверить условие

`i=5.`

При положительном исходе перейти к шагу 7. При отрицательном - перейти к шагу 5.

5. Выполнить вычисление

`U: = A(U) ⨁ ̅ Ci , V: = A(A(V)), W: =  U⨁ ̅V, Ki = P(W).`

6. Перейти к шагу 3.
7. Конец работы алгоритма.

Comment: 2 hex символа - это 1 байт.

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо, aepot. Я поняла, как это работает. Я недавно работаю с данным сайтом, не подскажешь, как можно показать, что твой ответ мне помог?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шестнадцатеричная система счисления. Один шестнадцатеричный символ - 4 бита (значение от 0 до 15). Соответственно 2 символа - 8 бит, то есть 1 байт.

Итого 64 символа = 32 байта.

Comment: aepot, можно узнать. Если бы ты делал, эту задачу какой тип данных для ключей и хеша ты бы выбрал в си Шарпе: byte? То есть сначала взял бы строку разбил по 2 символа, перенёс их в байтовое значение и каким-то способом занёс их значения в ключ. Всё верно? На данный момент я выбрала тип данных string[], но для генерации следующих ключей необходимо выполнить побитовое сложение слов одинаковой длины по модулю 2. С числами понятно, но вот со строками мне кажется не выйдет...

Comment: @ViktoriaNurieva конечо же `byte[]`, чтобы преобразовать в hex строку для отображения есть метод `string text = Convert.ToHexString(массив)`

Comment: Большое спасибо